# Using jsp can I get dynamic data to display in Open Graph protocol?

Tags: facebook, jsp, facebook-graph-api

I have a specific page in my application where I want a user to be able to share certain selections they have made on a previous page, selection which I am receiving from my database.

So, for example - I have a user - Barry. I can access his name using ${user}.

He have been asked a question:

- What is the first thing that comes to your mind when I ask about ${animals}

The answers they have chosen have been submitted to the DB, and I now want the answers to appear as the sharing description for Facebook. Obviously, the answer for each user will be unique - so I cannot hard code any information in here.

The code I have is the following:

```
<meta property="og:description" content="${user} thinks:%0A%0A<c:forEach var='animal' items='${animals}' >${animal} - ${animal.thoughts}%0A</c:forEach> />
```

When I view the source code for the page, I see this:

```
<meta property="og:description" content="Barry thinks:%0A%0AElephant - Gray%0ABird - Chirpy%0AMonkey - Funny%0ADog - Loyal />
```

However, when attempting to share the content on Facebook, the description is just empty, as though no description exists.

Unfortunately, this page is only available when the user is logged in, so using the Facebook scraper https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ simply shows me the og data of the logged out landing page.

Am I missing something here?

**EDIT**

Based on @Cbroe's comments below, I have now adapted the code to be shared on a public page (IE one that you do not need to be logged in to see).

I have also set the description and image location as parameters in the URL - so that anybody who shares this page will see a description and an image relevant to them.

When running the full URL through Facebook scraper, I see the exact results I am after:
[image: Link Preview]
However, when actually sharing the link from the application, the dynamic info from the URL is being ignored.

```
<meta property="og:description" content="${param.description}" />
<meta property="og:image" content="${param.image}" />
```

My og:url contains the full URL, including the dynamic parameters. If anyone else has any ideas, I would love to hear them.

**EDIT 2**

Link that helped CBroe debug has been removed due to company policy. Example link provided in my answer.

Comment: _“Am I missing something here?”_ - besides the obvious, you mean …? How do you expect the Facebook scraper to get at the data, if you hide it behind a login system the scraper knows nothing about?

Comment: @CBroe - I know why the scraper cannot get the data - but I still would have thought it would work when being shared from the page with the correct meta description?

Comment: Well, you thought wrong. The scraper will try to fetch the meta data from the URL you want to share. That request has no connection whatsoever to what your current page visitor is seeing, it is completely independent from that.

Comment: @cbroe - ok - but the scraper would not be able to get the dynamic info that the user has submitted anyway, would it? So is it even possible to share such dynamic data? As I mention in my post, when viewing the source of the page, the og:description has the dynamic data.

Comment: You need to create a unique URL for each unique piece of content you want to share, that returns the right meta data combination.

Comment: Interesting, ok - thanks for your comments - I will see what is possible using this approach with the application.

Comment: @CBroe - I have adapted my code based on your feedback, and the scraper now works well, but when trying to share the URL it is ignoring the dynamic data. I have edited my answer with more details. Do you have any ideas what the problem may be?

Comment: Can you show an actual example?

Comment: @CBroe - thanks for persisting with me :) - I have now added a link to the question. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: That seems to work fine now, shows the same data in preview on Facebook as in debug tool (well, description cut off at the end, but that is a length issue.) If you are still having issues, then it is likely either in the sharing part (not actually sharing the full URL), or an issue with scraping on first share (in that case, triggering a scrape of the URL via API helps.)

Comment: @CBroe - I am seeing the correct info in the debugger, and also when I put that link directly into a post - but when trying to use the Facebook share button (which is currently available on that link above), none of the meta info is coming through.

Comment: Well that's because you are indeed sharing the _wrong_ URL here - you need to properly URL-encode the value of the `u` parameter ...

Comment: @CBroe - I am really sorry to keep bothering you - but really appreciate your help - I have now encoded the URL - but I am back to square 1 - when using the share functionality, it is ignoring the dynamic parameters :(

Comment: Where? Not under the previous example URL, there I don't see any attempt at that.

Comment: It is in the URL mentioned above, I am now using a script to open the share dialog - and the URL is fully encoded in the popup.

Comment: Use `encodeURIComponent`, not `encodeURI` - the latter does _not_ encode all characters that have a special meaning in a URL.

Comment: @CBroe Oh wow, I owe you a beer sir. Thank you so much for your insight throughout this process. I will post the answer with all the suggestions you have made along the way. You have been a huge help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With massive thanks for @CBroe for baring with me through this process and helping me out in the comments, I have now got a solution to this problem.

Firstly, I created a client facing page that did not require the user to be logged in in order to view. This would act as the page that the dynamic content would be shared from.

The code that I have now looks something like this:

**Meta tags**

```
<meta property="og:title" content="My Title" />
<meta property="og:url" content="${pageUrl}" /> // generates FULL URL including all parameters
<meta property="og:description" content="${param.description}" />
<meta property="og:image" content="${param.image}" />
```

**Sharing generator (using jQuery)**

```
var currentLink = encodeURIComponent(window.location.href); // NB to use encodeURIComponent instead of just encodeURI
var tWindow;
$('.facebookShare').on('touchstart click', function(){
    tWindow = window.open('about:blank', 'sharer', 'toolbar=0,status=0,width=548,height=325');
    tWindow.location.href = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/share?app_id=${facebookAppId}&display=popup&href=' + currentLink;
});
```

The link that was then used to share the page looked something like this:

https://[myURL]?description=My%20favourite%20animals:%20Elephant%20-%20gray%20%7C%20Dog%20-%20Cute%20%7C%20Cat%20-%20Cant%20be%20trusted%20%7C%20Leopard%20-%20Never%20changes%20its%20spots&image=[url_to_my_image]

Using this code, when sharing the page, the correct (and dynamic) image and description were generated each time.

Once again, big ups to @CBroe for helping me get to the bottom of this - and I hope that this can help somebody else in the future.